# Why the number of wifi connections: 0?

Tags: java, android

I want to show Wifi connection list with android studio. There are 2 connections on wifi settings of my phone but my application doesn't see them.

Thanks in advance

When I open debug application i see this sentence:
Number Of Wifi connections : 0

So why It can't see wifi connections?
*I tried when wifi is enabled and when it's disabled.*

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
private TextView tv;
List<ScanResult> scanList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWifiNetworks);
    getWifiNetworksList();
}

private void getWifiNetworksList(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    final WifiManager wifiManager =
            (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);;
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf") @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            sb.append("\n  Number Of Wifi connections :" + " " +scanList.size()+"\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < scanList.size(); i++){
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ". ");
                sb.append((scanList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\n\n");
            }

            tv.setText(sb);
        }

    },filter);
    wifiManager.startScan();}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="hacker.wifi.mywifilist.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWifiNetworks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the location toggle of the device. Since Marshmallow it's a must.
Make sure that you have these permissions (you might omit some of them after testing, I took it from a similar project I did):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Check again please.

Comment: Thanks for help but it's still same. I tried all codes on the web about wifi scan list for android studio but I couldn't see any list until now. Do you recommend me any sample project about this issue? I'm about going crazy.

Comment: Do you always trying to check the list with debugging? Have you tried logging the results?

Comment: I just Run 'app'. How can I access log?

Comment: Never mind, I just noticed you are printing the results. Sorry, don't have any other ideas, good luck!